# How to know who recommended a ClearCase baseline?

Tags: clearcase, clearcase-ucm

Somebody recommended a baseline in my stream. How do I know how recommend it? I can only see who created it but didn't get any info who recommend it. Is there any specific command to see the history of the baseline/stream/view etc?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that meta-data is recorded.

You can check for the [policies attached to the UCM project though](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21147119)

```
POLICY_CHSTREAM_UNRESTRICTED
```

If it is *not* set, that means only the owner of the UCM project can change the recommended baseline on a stream.

---

Otherwise, as suggested below, **you would need to catch and record that event yourself through trigger**.
At the area of ClearCase 7.x (thos could have changed with CC8), this was done with a pre-op trigger on `chstream`, but it had to deal with two kind of interactions:

- CLI ([cleartool chstream -recommended](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSH27_8.0.1/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_chstream.htm?cp=SSSH27_8.0.1%2F4-0-0-0-2-4))
- GUI (through the "recommend baseline" contextual menu)

See for instance [this thread](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/forums/html/topic?id=77777777-0000-0000-0000-000014133098):

> `recommend_bls` trigger, with an early out check if `chstream` was not for a recommend baseline:

```perl
if ($ENV{CLEARCASE_CMDLINE}) {
  # chstream run from the command line, check for a "-recommended" option
  if ($ENV{CLEARCASE_CMDLINE} =~ /-recommend /) {
    $msg->D( "this is a chstream to recommend a baseline",
             "CLEARCASE_CMDLINE is: <$ENV{CLEARCASE_CMDLINE}>",
             "trigger proceeding...",
           );
  }
  else {
    $msg->D( "EARLY OUT - this chstream command does not include a
              baseline recommend:",
             "CLEARCASE_CMDLINE is: <$ENV{CLEARCASE_CMDLINE}>",
           );
    exit 1;
  }
}
else {
  # chstream was run from the gui, must look at event records to
  # determine if the command was a baseline recommend or 
  # some other change to the stream
  my $lshist_rc = qx($CT lshist -minor -last 1 -me stream:$ENV{CLEARCASE_STREAM});
  if ($?) {
    # error in the lshist command, report trigger error
    my @args = ("$CP proceed -type error -default abort -mask abort -newline -prompt \"***RECOMMEND_BL Trigger Version: $VERSION***\n\n<lshist> cmd failed on
stream:$ENV{CLEARCASE_STREAM}.\nResults:\n$lshist_rc\nPlease send a
screen print of this error to your ClearCase admin.\" -prefer_gui");
    system (@args);
    $msg->D( "Processing aborted - lshist command failed!",
             "$lshist_rc"
           );
    exit 11;
  }
  chomp($lshist_rc);
  # check latest stream event record to see if the chstream was 
  # a baseline recommend or some other change to the stream.
  # a baseline recommend will have an event record of the form:
  # "Set activity process variable named "UCM_STREAM_RECBLS".
  if ($lshist_rc =~ /UCM_STREAM_RECBLS/) {
    $msg->D( "this is a chstream to recommend a baseline",
             "latest event record on stream is:",
             "$lshist_rc",
             "trigger proceeding...",
           );
  }
  else {
    $msg->D( "EARLY OUT - this chstream command did not include a baseline recommend:",
             "latest event record on stream is:",
             "$lshist_rc",
           );
    exit 1;
  }
}
```

Comment: i need to see what happen in the stream. I had POLICY_CHSTREAM_UNRESTRICTED enabled. SO there is not history command to see?

Comment: @user2370590 no, none of the usual commands seem to give any result, as illustrated by: https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/forums/html/topic?id=77777777-0000-0000-0000-000014458265

Comment: @user2370590 try a `cleartool lshis -minor` on the stream or the baseline, just in case though. the `-min` option (`-minor`) might help.